# XML PHP MYSQL data parsing

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I am having a question to ask...
I am having a mysql database...
I want to make an XML file for my mysql database using PHP
I did it using newXMLELEMENT function..
Now next thing i want to do is parse my XML file data to HTML Tables & Forms..
Hoe can i add XML data to html textbox and other controls..?

```
           <?php
              $xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
              $xmlDoc->load("userimages.xml");
              $x = $xmlDoc->documentElement;
                  foreach ($x->childNodes AS $item)
                         {
                           print $item->nodeName . " = " . $item->nodeValue . "<br>";
                         }
           ?>
```

this is my code..i wan tot add the fetched data to forms....but its getting print simply as i am using print function
this is my XML
i want to parse all this data in my forms ex. , etc to disabled textbox,

```
    <ALLIMAGES>
    <gal>
       <imageid>6</imageid>
       <imagetype>Vector</imagetype>
       <image>..images/accept.png</image>
       <companyname>w845</companyname>
       <description>villain</description>
       <status>sold</status>
       <dou>2014-03-16</dou>
       <like>22</like>
       <price>212</price>
       <color>BLUE</color>
   </gal>

   <gal>
       <imageid>7</imageid>
       <imagetype/>
       <image/>
       <companyname>amit</companyname>
       <description>sdfj</description>
       <status>Not Sold</status>
       <dou>2014-01-01</dou>
       <like>0</like>
       <price>123</price>
       <color/>
   </gal>
```

Comment: Why are you using `DOMDocument` for parsing `XML` ? Use [`simplexml_load_file`](http://in1.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php)

Comment: i have posted above..!
Thnx for response letme check

Comment: Post your XML data on your question and show what you needed to be extracted.

Comment: have posted above..pls chk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just an illustration and it works as shown.. Spoonfeeding is not good, so you try to explore more with this code..

```
<?php
$xml=' <ALLIMAGES>
    <gal>
       <imageid>6</imageid>
       <imagetype>Vector</imagetype>
       <image>..images/accept.png</image>
       <companyname>w845</companyname>
       <description>villain</description>
       <status>sold</status>
       <dou>2014-03-16</dou>
       <like>22</like>
       <price>212</price>
       <color>BLUE</color>
   </gal>

   <gal>
       <imageid>7</imageid>
       <imagetype/>
       <image/>
       <companyname>amit</companyname>
       <description>sdfj</description>
       <status>Not Sold</status>
       <dou>2014-01-01</dou>
       <like>0</like>
       <price>123</price>
       <color/>
   </gal>
</ALLIMAGES>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
echo "<pre>";
echo "<form method='post' action=''>";
foreach ($xml->gal as $tag)
{
   echo "Image ID : <input type='text' value=$tag->imageid />";echo "<br>";
   echo "Company Name: <input type='text' value=$tag->companyname />";echo "<br>";

}
echo "</form>";
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

[image]

Comment: yaa their are 'n' no. of articles for spoon feeding where i can just copy paste codes and it will work...but i dont do it until m aware wat m copying paste...thnq for soo awesome explantn...
Still problem is u have just pasted my XML data in to a variable...but my data automatically updates..!
What to do for that?

Comment: Simple.. copy the `XML` data into a file say `users.xml`. In the above code replace the `simple_xml_load_string` with `$xml = simplexml_load_file('users.xml');`